# Windows Phone 8 keyboard extension

Tags: input, keyboard, windows-phone-8

As i remember this is not possible in Windows Phone 7, but maybe something has changed..

Here is the task: i need to add georgian keyboard to windows phone. WP8 can open georgian characters, but there still is no keyboard to enter georgian texts. My previous solution for WP7 was embedded font+custom drawn keyboard layout. Can i change the default keyboard layout programmatically or for example create keyboard package like for russian keyboard, tho russian one is downloading as package from microsoft and i need to create such package from "third party" webaddress?
 Or may be i can contact microsoft and be volunteer to create georgian layout and suggestions list, but i dont know how and don't think they will agree to add new language input method into minor os update.

**PS** sure i need to be able to do that change without developer update on client phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed here from WP7. WP8 doesn't support 3rd party keyboard extensions. From the consumer aspect WP8 has made great strides in improving globalization support and I'm sure your russian users are OK with their default russian keyboard.

Comment: Russian users are OK :) But georgians are not russians, they have their language and writing. And what about another option..Can i contact microsoft somehow and help them with layout or dont know?..Anyway, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

0x49D1, consider using [THIS](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx), with customizations. I'm working in a project where we use a custom keyboard. With some extra codes and customizations I've made a custom softkeyboard, as you can see in the screenshot bellow. Right now, my softkeyboard is working properly, but with some issues to be resolved yet.

[image]

My custom WP keyboard problems are:

- There's no caret cursor;
- The TextBox in my screen is a AutoCompleteBox, and when it opens the completions, my keyboard loses focus, and so I need an extra tap (this is my greates problem now)
- WP native keyboard try to slide up when I choose an item within the completions

Comment: Ive already made custom keyboard for wp7 using this project. Was wondering if the situation has changed. http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/georgian-keyboard/0de65c8f-df5c-43cd-bfe5-903444f6f398 better than nothing :)

Comment: Instead of textbox i've used custom control based on textblock. And about carret - im "simulating" it with "|".